# Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'

Tags: swift

I have the following Model:

```
struct MyModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let data: ASubModelData
    let error: Bool?
    let error_message: String?
    let error_code: Int?
}
```

and I'm trying to create a variable in a view so I can then assign the values to it like this:

```
@State var myVar: MyModel? = MyModel()
```

but it's throwing an error:

```
Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'
```

[image]

If I hit fix, it would be like:

```
@State var myVar: MyModel? = MyModel(from: Decoder)
```

and that's wrong, it also gives an error, how can I create a variable that is an empty instance of that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct` has no initializer other than the one for decoding. You have to add the initializer `init()`:

```
init() {
  data = ?
  error = nil
  error_message = nil
  error_code = nil
}
```

However, since `MyModel` contains properties that are not optional, it would be probably better to initialize it with a `nil`:

```
@State var myVar: MyModel?
```

Comment: only the second part was sufficient apparently :) Thank you